# C++ - Using 'i' to check different variables in a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what to call this, so I'm also not sure what to search for, but is there a way to use 'i' as part of a variable name within a for loop? Using C++ by the way.

For example,

```
int int1, int2, int3;
for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++){
     //somehow use i as inti or int+i, etc.
     //I was wondering if this is possible?
}
```

I appreciate any input.

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you doing that already?

Answer (score 16):

use an array

```
int ints [3];
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
     int x = ints[i];
}
```

Comment: i wrote the answer, look away for 5 seconds to check to make sure I remember c arrays correctly, and i already got 5 upvotes

Comment: Well, you missed one thing. They start at index 0. But 12 votes in a minute is insane :p

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why would he use std::vector? He's not intending to add any new items.

Comment: And I don't understand why do people forget to come back after asking a question. A question with 16 upvotes is still unaccepted. This as well is insane.

Answer (score 6):

Department for insane solutions:

```
int int1, int2, int3;
int *arr[3] = { &int1, &int2, &int3 };
for(int i = 1; i<=3; i++){
   ... *arr[i] ... 
}
```

would also work, but not as easy as using an array, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ you should pick up one of the containers from the C++ standard library, as `[std::array]`[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or `[std::vector]`[2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::array<int, 3> const ia = {{ 2, 4, 8 }};

  for( int i : ia ) {
    std::cout << "[" << i << "] ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```